# Mysql: use value as alias in query

Tags: mysql

given a table

```
create table mymy(A int(2),B int(2))
```

is it possible to use a field value as an alias? Something like (not really):

```
select A as valueOf(B) from mymy.
```

Comment: Not clear what you want to ask ?

Comment: I think the straightforward answer is "no." But if you say more about what you want to do with the results of this query, we may be able to help find a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can't. The values are not known until the query is run. And even if you could, you'd have a lot of possibly different values in one column. Which one should be used?

The only valid reason I can imagine for such a request is that you have some kind of EAV design and you want to have a Pivot result.

If that's the case, you could use Dymanic SQL (run a query, get the results, build another query based on those results and run that one.) But this kind of operations is better done at the application side (get the results and format them there, as you prefer).

Comment: My guess exactly, a Pivot table you need.

Comment: Search StackOverflow for [`[mysql][pivot]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql+pivot). Also check this site [http://www.artfulsoftware.com](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78) which has a few examples.