# Join Three tables in mysql with weird requirement

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables in my db.

`Table A` has the fields

```
KEYID | KeyName
27    | Income
28    | Account Number
```

`Table B` has the fields

```
UserID | Email          | Name | Phone
481    | test@gmail.com | test | 99999999
```

`Table C` has the fields

```
ID | KEYID | UserID | Value
1  |   27  |   481  | 10,000
```

I need to display the table fields headers are:

```
UserID | Email          | Name |   Phone  | Income
```

and the table values should be like this:

```
 481   | test@gmail.com | test | 99999999 | 10,000
```

I can get the KeyIDs which should be displayed in the table. In this example the KeyIDs string is '27' . I tried with joining and i can fetch & display the value in the table. but i dont know how i can show the key name as table header.

Any Idea.?

Comment: use `AS` in your query.Please post the query.

Comment: Use "AS" to name-alias your fields.
SELECT `id` AS `userID` FROM TABLE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql: use value as alias in query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9642324/mysql-use-value-as-alias-in-query)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423572/dynamic-column-alias-based-on-column-value and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226138/mysql-use-value-from-another-table-as-column-alias

Comment: *"but i dont know how i can show the key name as table header."* -- is this a [tag:mysql] question or an [tag:html] question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pair of inner join

```
select b.UserID, b.Email , b.Name, c.value as income 
from   tableB as b inner join tableC as C on b.userID = c.userId
inner join tableA as a on a.keyID = c.keyID 
and a.keyname = 'Income';
```

and the query you provided in comment

```
select 
      b.UserID
    , b.Email 
    , b.Name
    , Group_Concat(Distinct Concat(c.keyID,’^:^’,c.value) 
                          Order By c.id Separator ‘;’) As Keyvalues 
    from tableB as b 
    inner join tableC as C on b.userID = c.userId 
    inner join tableA as a on a.keyID = c.keyID;
```

and with CASE  should be

```
 select 
      b.UserID
    , b.Email 
    , b.Name
    , Group_Concat(Distinct CASE 
            WHEN c.keyID IN ('1,23,10') THEN Concat(c.keyID,’^:^’,c.value) END  
            Order By c.id Separator ‘;’) As Keyvalues 
    from tableB as b 
    inner join tableC as C on b.userID = c.userId 
    inner join tableA as a on a.keyID = c.keyID;
```

Comment: Hi.. thanks for your help.. i've used your answer but with a little change.. here is the query i've used. 

select b.UserID, b.Email , b.Name, 
Group_Concat(Distinct Concat(c.keyID,’^:^’,c.value) Order By c.id Separator ‘;’) As Keyvalues 
from   tableB as b inner join tableC as C on b.userID = c.userId
inner join tableA as a on a.keyID = c.keyID;

This gives a result i want.. but one thing i need to avoid from this query is to fetch only values of specific keyids from table c instead of all id and value pair. I've the list of keyids in an array. can i use CASE statement in group concat?

Comment: I have added you answer below the mine ..for a better readability .. .. anyway you can use CASE statement  on every column .. CASE work like a multi if .. substantilally

Comment: I tried like 
Group_Concat(Distinct CASE WHEN c.keyID IN ('1,23,10') Concat(c.keyID,’^:^’,c.value) 
                          Order By c.id Separator ‘;’) As Keyvalues 

this throws me a syntax error .. can you plz tell me the correct usage ?

Comment: You missed the then ...end in case  .. i have update the answer  .. hope is useful

Comment: Wow.. Thanks.. And one more doubt.. While running the query it gives the Keyvalues column with only '1^:^test' . the remaining id values are not there. is it because of using IN ?? i need the keyvalues column should contain " 1^:^test;23^:^test1;10^:^test2" ..And if any value of a particular ID is not present in that case it should return NULL ... It  seems that the query is taking only the first ID given in the IN array ... Do you know how to avoid this ?

Comment: If you don't have all the key in table c you should use left join  ...but without a proper sample is notb easy  .. tell you the right answer .. for this .. strating form the answer provided .. you should post a new question with proper sample  .. specifically related ad the result .. you  ... otherwise is difficult  .. followr your question .. during changing ..

Comment: Sorry.. My Mistake.. I got the correct answer now... Thanks You soo much for your help :)

Comment: Well you can also rate my answer as useful .. if you agree

Answer (score 0):

This query should help to get your desire result.

```
select b.UserID, b.Email, b.Name, b.Phone, c.Value as Income
from table_b as b
JOIN table_c as c ON (b.UserID = c.UserID)
where c.KEYID = 27
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT b.userid, b.email, b.name, b.phone, c.value as income
FROM a
LEFT JOIN c on c.keyid = a.keyid
LEFT JOIN b ob b.userid = c.userid
```